# Is there a way to let Python generate multiple if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, auto-generate

I just need to add +30 to every number in every if statement. I need 36 of these, is there a way to let turtle make more if statements or something similar? I'm really stuck and the manual way would be crazy.

For example:

```
if 0 <= x <=30 and 0 <= y <= 30:
      turtle.drawsstuff

if 30 <= x <=60 and 0 <= y <= 60:

etc.
```

Comment: It depends on your if statements

Comment: What's in the if-statement bodies?

Comment: turtle fills a square

Comment: If you need this, you're doing something the hard way or doing the wrong thing altogether.

Answer (score 5):

Use a for loop.

```
for n in range(0, 36 * 30, 30):
    if n <= x <= n + 30 and 0 <= y <= n + 30:
        pass #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for n in range(0, 36 * 30, 30):
    if n <= x <= (n+30) and n <= y <= (n+30):
        pass  # (do stuff)
```

`range` can take an optional third argument for the "step" value. For reference, see [Python's documentation on `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).